# writing a plist in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist

I know there are many topics with similar issues, but I have not been able to find a topic addressing my question.

I want to store a plist of highscores.
Every entry of highscores must have two elements
an NSString* and an int.

I want to store the top 20 high scores (pairs of strings and ints) and do that in a plist.

I start with:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mylist" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

I want the item 0 of the array to be a dictionary, where I can insert key value pairs of
(string, int)
How do I do that?

Comment: Three comments: 1. Is the root element of your plist is really an array? I doubt. You'd rather want to initialize an NSMutableDictionary for your purpose. 2. Then you can't insert an object at index 0, as the dictionary is an *unordered* collection. 3. Before you ask it in another question: you WON'T be able to rewrite the plist to the app's main bundle directory becuse an app cannot possibly write to its own bundle.

Comment: Even if you store NSMutableDictionary objects in your array and save it, when you load it they will be immutable.  ([NSArray Class Reference for initWithContentsOfFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfFile:) says "The objects contained by this array are immutable, even if the array is mutable.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always call `[arr addObject:score];`, sort it, and remove the final item until there are 10.

To sort:

```
[arr sortUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    NSDictionary *firstDict = (NSDictionary *)firstObject;
    NSDictionary *secondDict = (NSDictionary *)secondObject;
    int firstScore = [[firstDict objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
    int secondScore = [[secondDict objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
    return firstScore < secondScore ? NSOrderedAscending : firstScore > secondScore : NSOrderedDescending : NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

If you want the scores to be the other way around, change the '>' to '<' and vice-versa. To keep the list down to 10:

```
while ([arr count] > 10) {
    [arr removeLastObject];
}
```

You may have to sort when you load from your plist. For 10 scores the performance hit will be minimal, so I suggest you do it just in case.

Comment: That is helpful indeed! But, the problem is I want to be storing both a score and a string for every score. Are you saying that the key should be the string and then the value of the key should be the score?

Answer (score 1):

[Property List Serialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html)

You will want to make notice of: the mutability option, as your method probably returns immutable arrays...

storing in a plist is done with the `writeToFile:...` or `writeToURL:...` methods

Comment: also it is usually very bad practice to have the root of a plist as an array, unless it is non-determanistic in regard to order.

Answer (score 0):

```
[arr insertObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] atIndex:0];
```

Comment: First, thanks for the comment.
Second, to clarify something. My goal is to store in a plist, in someway, I am not sure how (I am thinking the way I described above) the 10 top high scores (their details constitute of a pair of an int and NSString*. Every time I want to check if I the int I am inserting is higher than the 10 ints already in there and if yes, insert and remove the minimum int (if they are more than 10 overall). Is that clearer?